# How to link to a label at hyperref?

Tags: hyperref, labels

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true]
 {hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

abc
\newpage
$CBC$: \label{cbc}
\newpage
\hyperref[cbc]{$CBC$}

\end{document}
```

As you can see (if you run it) the `\hyperref[cbc]{$CBC$}` don't links to the label `cbc`, instead it links to the top of the page...
Do you know why?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried with `\hypertarget` instead `\label`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition you need to use are

```
\hypertarget{cbc}{$CBC$}
```

and

```
\hyperlink{cbc}{$CBC$}
```

which means that `cbc` is the used label and `$CBC$` is the displayed text in the document.

So with the complete code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[%
  unicode=true,
  pdfusetitle,
  bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
  breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=false,colorlinks=true
]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
 linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

abc
\newpage
\hypertarget{cbc}{$CBC$:} % \label{cbc} <===============================
\newpage
Link to cbs working? 

\hyperlink{cbc}{$CBC$} % <==============================================

\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image: link]

and the target is shown as:

[image: target]